# What *is* a Browser.Navigation.Key in Elm?

Tags: elm

I'm starting to work with Elm's `Browser.application` which is a lot of fun, but one thing that (as far as I can tell) is never really explained is the `Browser.Navigation.Key` type.

[The elm docs](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/browser/1.0.2/Browser-Navigation#Key) say

> A navigation Key is needed to create navigation commands that change the URL. That includes pushUrl, replaceUrl, back, and forward.

And I think at this point I think I pretty much get how to use it from following examples in the elm guide, but I am very curious, just academically:

- What sort of information does this type hold?
- How is that information used by elm's navigation internally?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I haven't used Elm in a while but was curious about this myself.

At first glance, the key mechanism solves a problem outlined here: https://github.com/elm/browser/blob/1.0.2/notes/navigation-in-elements.md —or at least has something to do with that contention.

The immediate takeaway is that they wanted to prohibit you from accessing the URL-changing API unless you created your app with `Browser.application`, so one way to do that would be to require a dummy type like `Key` as input that you can only get  if you use `Browser.application`. But there's more to the key than that.

[`Browser.application`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/browser/1.0.2/Browser#application), unlike `Browser.document` and `Browser.element`, gives you additional handlers: `onUrlRequest` and `onUrlChange`.

So, how is it communicated to your application when the URL changes? How is it implemented?

The source code here explains a lot: https://github.com/elm/browser/blob/53e3caa265fd9da3ec9880d47bb95eed6fe24ee6/src/Elm/Kernel/Browser.js#L142

In particular, this is what's held in the `Key` opaque type:

```js
var key = function() { key.__sendToApp(onUrlChange(_Browser_getUrl())); };
```

When you use `Browser.application`, the initialization code wires url-change listeners to call `key()`:

```
_Browser_window.addEventListener('popstate', key);
_Browser_window.addEventListener('hashchange', key);
```

And URL-changing functions also call `key()`:

```
var _Browser_pushUrl = F2(function(key, url)
{
    return A2(__Task_perform, __Basics_never, __Scheduler_binding(function() {
        history.pushState({}, '', url);
        key();
    }));
});
```

The key mechanism is a simple way for the API know where to route URL-change updates to: simple, the code requires that you give it the `key` function that will call `app.onUrlChange(...)` on the app that created it.

This still doesn't seem to completely answer one technical part of the question to me: Why do you need to pass key to Navigation.{go,push,replace}? Doesn't the code above (`_Browser_window.addEventListener('popstate', key)`) already call `key()` when the URL changes?

It turns out that the `popstate` event only fires for UI interactions like clicking the back button. The event isn't called when you use `history.{push,replace}State(..., url)` directly which of course is what this library is doing: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onpopstate

In other words, it seems the key mechanism exists as a simple stateless way for the `go`, `pushUrl`, `replaceUrl` functions (https://github.com/elm/browser/blob/53e3caa265fd9da3ec9880d47bb95eed6fe24ee6/src/Elm/Kernel/Browser.js#L190-L212) to have a way to call the currently running application's `onUrlChange`. Else the API could have probably gotten away with just the `_Browser_window.addEventListener('popstate', key)` line in `Browser.application` initialization. But that event is never emitted when the URL is changed from Javascript, so they needed a way to call `app.onUrlChange()` directly inside those functions, aka `key()`.

And, of course, it has the additional pay-off of scoping the URL API to only applications created with `Browser.application`. Bit of a rambling answer, but I didn't have time to write a shorter one. ;)